# Can't get Dejavu Serif Bold to work as a font for HTML Canvas, what gives?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fonts, font-face

So I have a jsFiddle containing a canvas with a screenshot/image drawn on it showing my text being displayed in a font manager using the correct font (Dejavu Serif Bold) and displaying correctly. Then I attempt to draw the same text above the text in the screenshot with the same font using @font-face and html canvas but it doesn't look the same (you can best tell from the moon and the circle with a dot inside it), how come?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gautamadude/zMKge/1544/

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Dejavu Serif Bold';
    src: url('http://labrador.is/media/media/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf');
}
```

Javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
var dejavu_look = new Image();
dejavu_look.src = "http://labrador.is/media/media/dejavu_visual.png";
dejavu_look.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0,this.width, this.height);
  ctx.font         = 'bold 50px "Dejavu Serif Bold"';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'orangered';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText  ('♇♆♄♃♂☉♀☿☽⨁', 220, 320);
};
```

Comment: What browser is this not working with? Chrome handles it fine.

Comment: @Blender I'm running "Chromium Version 26.0.1410.43 Debian 7.0 (189671)". I just tried it in Firefox/Iceweasel 20.0 though and it seems to work fine there.